# Invalid URI error during web test run

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I have create a very simple webtest that had just one request to one simple URL that is like that: `https://www.domain.com/`.

When I run the test though I get Failed and this message:

> Request failed: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be
>   determined.

But the Response tab has the proper response `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` with lots of HTML. Is this a bug in Visual Studio or something and is there a way to ensure that it does not treat proper requests as failed?

P.S.
I have also noticed that request takes like 10 - 15 seconds, even though the RequestTime (that the visual studio shows) is really less than 1.

Comment: What is shown in the "details" tab?

Comment: I have deleted all the validation rules (though they were success before). The error is :System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. .......
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestCaseVariation.AddParsedDependentRequests(ExecutionState executionState). Seems it's something with dependent requests, but I am not quite sure what that is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTML of most web pages requires a collection of other files to be downloaded, such as images, JSON, CSS, JavaScript, etc. These are the dependant requests. Visual Studio examines the HTML to find the set of dependant requests. They should all be valid URLs. The Visual Studio code that extracts these dependant requests is less forgiving than many browsers. Visual Studio requires them to be valid URLs. Many real browsers work hard to cope with bad HTML so that something sensible can be shown.

The reason for the exception is probably badly formatted HTML in the response. Some browsers have developer facilities that will describe errors found in the downloaded html. Check what these developer facilities say about errors on the page; it may be worth trying several browsers to get different assessments of the page.

One example: a malformed [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) can lead to the exception you report.

---

When looking at the web test execution log for a successful request you will see the dependant requests listed. It appears that Visual Studio "trusts" that these requests form valid URLs, ie they are properly formatted. Your test has a badly formatted URL. If you had given a properly formatted URL but there was no resource then you would have seen the dependant request and seen it get 404 error. This is an edge case and you might argue that Visual Studio should report it differently.

By "web test execution log" I refers to the way the results of a web test are shown. That is the tabular form with the column titles: Request + Status + Total time + Request time + Request bytes + Response bytes. Below that there are tabs showing details of the selected item, the tabs are labelled Web browser + Request + Response + Context + Details. If you click the little triangles at the left-hand side of the "Request" column you will see the redirections and the dependant requests. (Note that logs for web tests run within a load test omit dependant request details.)

Comment: I did not know that Visual Studio does that. I really thought it only executes requests that are recorded and visible in the structure. It is very uninformative not to say the line or something with the error... That should not really fail the whole test either, since 200 is enough, but I guess that's the way it works and it's not very configurable :)

Comment: Could you please specify where to find this "web test log of successful requests". I am not able to find any listed dependent requests.

Answer (score 3):

Setting "Parse Dependent Requests" to False for that specific call helps.

Comment: But doing so would prevent all its other valid dependent requests from being issued. That would lessen the load and put the validity of the load test into question.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to catch the invalid URI value in VS debugger:

- Generate code for the webtest (with a toolbar button)
- Set debugger to stop when any CLR exception is thrown
- Add a breakpoint before the faulty request
- Run it under debugger (via right click in code)
- When the breakpoint is hit attach to QTDCAgent32.exe process
- Run the test

You will be asked for a source file that you don't have but it's OK. The Locals debugger window shows the faulty URI. Depending on availability of debug symbols you may have to re-run the test several times (until all symbols are loaded).

**Update:**

AdrianHHH was right - the problem was in the "base" tag. It looks like this:

```
 <base href='/foo/'>
```

In HTML4 it was illegal, but in HTML5 it's a valid construct. But VS2013 webtest engine fails here.